# Get Data from iOS device using Bluetooth in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, cbcentralmanager

I am working on an application that needs to get details of another Bluetooth device when it starts scanning the nearby devices. I have managed to get a few and I am stuck at few values that I am not receiving.

Values which are needed. 
1. UUID
2. rssi
3. txpower
4. Detected Device Name
5. data
6. distance
7. time
8. mac address

Out of which I have managed to get UUID, rssi, Detected Device Name and time.

I am not able to figure out how to get txpower, data, distance and mac address.

Data should be in string format.

Below are my code and output.

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
    let rssi = RSSI.stringValue
    print("UUID:",uuid)
    print("Device Name:",peripheral.name!)
    print("rssi:",rssi)
    print("Ad Data:", advertisementData)
    print("time:", advertisementData["kCBAdvDataTimestamp"]!)
    print("peripheral:", peripheral)
    if let power = advertisementData["kCBAdvDataTxPowerLevel"] as? Double{
    print("power:", power)
    print("Distance is ", pow(10, ((power - Double(truncating: RSSI))/20)))
 }
```

> OUTPUT

```
UUID: A863C72A-DCB7-43DB-9431-5F0107CB3474
Device Name: iPhone 7
rssi: -12
Ad Data: ["kCBAdvDataTimestamp": 610053944.490985, "kCBAdvDataIsConnectable": 1]
time: 610053944.490985 
peripheral: <CBPeripheral: 0x2808d0780, identifier = 9511F67B-9903-7D50-467A-BAAF4ECA1479, name = iPhone 7, state = disconnected>
```

Please help me get this data, I have searched the internet but didn't find any relevant answer. Hence posting it here

TIA

Answer (score 0):

MAC address is not exposed to application layer in iOS due to privacy.

TX power is filtered away in the advertisement, i.e., not exposed to application layer either.

So it is simply not possible on iOS, sorry.

Cheers!